# How to secure Solr on Tomcat with ProxyPass setup?

Tags: security, tomcat, solr

I want to prevent the outside world from accessing solr.  According to the intructions I have found elsewhere on the web I can do this by adding the following line to my tomcat server.xml file.

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="127.0.0.1"/>
```

That seems to work well.

However, I have a Jquery app that sends select queries to solr in order to return results.

Since adding this line, Jquery responses are returning a 403 error.

I'm guessing the issue is that because I'm using Jquery, it's the client's IP that is trying to access solr and not the localhost.

But I'm confused because I had set up a proxypass in apache to access solr and thought that this would use the localhost I.P in that case.

Here's my Proxypass setup:

```
# Proxy specific settings
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost Off

<Proxy *>
    AddDefaultCharset off
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /solrsearch http://localhost:8080/solr/collection1/select
ProxyPassReverse /solrsearch http://localhost:8080/solr/collection1/select
```

What do I need to do to make sure that apache acts as a proxy and does not pass the client's IP to solr?

Comment: If you are "protecting" Solr, then poking a hole for anyone to be able to get through, what are you really achieving?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.  What I want to achieve is allowing only the server to make requests to solr.  This already works using the tomcat configuration above.  The proxypass + jquery would, in theory, only allow select requests to be made, I'm perfectly ok with this.  The trouble is that Jquery requests are currently being blocked even though I am making requests via the proxy 'solrsearch', it was my understanding that the proxy would use the I.P 127.0.0.1 and therefore should pass through the tomcat rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this work.

After turning on tomcat's access logging I was able to see that requests made to

http://mydomain.com/solrsearch where being made using the I.P `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`

So I changed my server.xml rule to

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"/>
```

Now it all works!  My Jquery live search is able to make queries but any attempt to connect to solr from another URL (such as the admin interface or an update url) cannot be accessed from the outside world.

Comment: For robustness, you might want to allow either `127.0.0.1` or `::1` (expanded, of course, since Java doesn't do IPv6 abbreviations).